# How to solve react multiple components under one component CPU loading high issue?

Tags: reactjs

During our react website development we have encountered a problem, say we have a page full of different components, our current design is all the components are "under" one mother component, when any component updated, it "report" the changed value to mother by calling a function of mother component, and mother component will do some "data massage" and then store the value in her state. However, since mother component state changed, this will cause all it's children component recalculate/re-render , which cause extremely high CPU loading and the browser even hang because of this.

I hope to seek for advice in this scenario what is the best way to handle this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement either React.memo or React.PureComponent in the child components in order to prevent re-render of the components when their props have not changed.

Here is a link to the documentation for how to implement this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent